# Docker inspect with unix:///var/run/docker.sock (in Java or Scala)

Tags: java, scala, docker

Docker has lots of interesting information available via unix:///var/run/docker.sock

I have been able to map this to a port and I can access /containers/json with GET requests to the port.  But... this is not exactly secure.

How can I access /containers/json from this raw socket file (in Java or Scala)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use pure java as there is no framework support for Unix sockets. However, you can use some sort of jni-library for this. Like [this one](https://github.com/mcfunley/juds).